# Unit firewalld.service is masked

Tags: firewalld

When I want to start the firewalld service, I got this error

```
[root@servera ~]# systemctl start firewalld
Failed to start firewalld.service: Unit firewalld.service is masked.
```

and I searched in the web and got a solution that run `systemctl unmask firewalld`, but it is not working, others get a message `Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/firewalld.service.` but I got nothing.
When I want to `enable` this service, I got an error

```
[root@servera ~]# systemctl enable firewalld
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service is masked.
```

It's abnormal, because it's `/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service`, not `/etc/systemd/system/firewalld.service`

Any hints? Thanks!

I have tried

```
systemctl unmask firewalld
```

but it's no response and not working

Answer (score 0):

There's another post on stack overfhlow where I found the answer for me. It appears to be the same on three of my RH systems, RHEL7/8/9.

```
systemctl unmask --now firewalld
```